# Wordpress login with username, email and custom meta field

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook, wordpress-login

I'm working on a custom Wordpress login form. At the moment users are able to login with their username or email but i also want to add the option to user their account-number. The account number is a custom metafield and is different form the id.

I've found the following hooks

- wp_authenticate_user
- wp_authenticate_username_password

but i've online seen options to remove the username of email not ways to add meta fields.

Kind regards

Comment: Please your code here which have you tried?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

Answer (score 0):

You need to add account number field to login form and then check or validate according to your need using `wp_authenticate_user` hook.

So you can try something like this:

```
//Add account number field on login form
add_action( 'login_form', 'myplugin_add_login_fields' );
function myplugin_add_login_fields() {
    $account_number = ( isset( $_POST['account_number'] ) ) ? $_POST['account_number'] : '';
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="account_number"><?php _e('Account Number','mydomain') ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="account_number" id="account_number" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($account_number)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

//check if account number is present or throw error if its not provided by the user.
//do any extra validation stuff here e.g. get account number from DB
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user','check_account_number', 10, 2);
function check_account_number($user, $password) {
    $return_value = $user;
    $account_number = ( isset( $_POST['account_number'] ) ) ? $_POST['account_number'] : '';
    if(empty($account_number)) {
        $return_value = new WP_Error( 'empty_account_number', 'Please enter account number.' );
    }

    //stop user from logging in if its account number is incorrect
    $account_number_db = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'lidnummer', true);
    if($account_number_db != $account_number) {
        $return_value = new WP_Error( 'invalid_account', 'Please enter your correct account number.' );
    }

    return $return_value;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use the same input field as the username/email for the account number. So the user could login with only his accountnumber and password?

Comment: How are you trying to save account number in database?

Comment: I have added is a an meta_key. The key is named "lidnummer". Here is the database row for 1 user: [Database Row](https://imgur.com/a/jcqKiSX).

Comment: You need the username or email because you have no other way to get the user ID, so you need to user ID to get the user meta and only then you can verify the account number i have updated my answer that will throw error if user's account number don't match with the entered one.